# Does Jason's actions violate 2 of the rules of being a Power Ranger?

Tags: power-rangers, power-rangers-2017

In the new Power Ranger movie, during the fight with Rita, Jason notices his father's truck is flipped and on fire. He runs over, fighting putty's along the way, and rips the door off. He then calls his dad by name. There's recognition in his dad's face as he realizes who the Red Ranger is.

Now, the rules of the Power Rangers are:

> Rule #1 Never use your power for personal gain
>
> Rule #2 Never escalate a battle unless forced
>
> Rule #3 Always keep your identity a secret no one may know that you are a power ranger.

My question is, did he violate rules 1 and 3 by saving his father?

Comment: I'm not sure you could call rescuing someone from fire "personal gain"

Comment: ..or someone guessing your identity "revealing".

Comment: @Valorum: It's the fact that he went out of his way to save this ONE person, who happened to be his father.

Comment: @Paulie_D: He called his dad by name, in an effort to get him to trust him. Thus, revealing his identity, of a sorts.

Comment: You're forgetting the all-important caveat that applies to *all* superhero rules, which goes as follows: "unless you really, really want to." :-)

Comment: Or unless the writing is especially terrible.

Comment: I thought the two rules of being a Power Ranger were don’t talk about being a Power Ranger, and don’t talk about being a Power Ranger.

Comment: Discussion on Movies.SE (and my own personal experience) suggests that Rule 3 in general is complete baloney. The villains always seem to know who the Power Rangers are and go out of their way to target them directly.

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking none of the rules were violated.

While he may have gone out of his way to rescue his father he probably would have gone out of his way to rescue anyone in a flipped over and burning truck.

Calling someone by name really isn't revealing your identity its not like someones name is a secret.